Virtual soft photons Weinberg volume I chapter 13.2
In chapter 13.2 volume I Weinberg claims that
\begin{equation}
M^\lambda_{\beta\alpha}=M^\Lambda_{\beta\alpha}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^4}\sum_{nm}e_ne_m\eta_n\eta_mJ_{nm}\right),\tag{13.2.4}
\end{equation}
where $M^\lambda_{\beta\alpha}$ is the matrix element for a process $\alpha\to \beta$ including radiative corrections of any number of soft photons with momenta $|\boldsymbol{q}|\ge \lambda$ while $M^\Lambda_{\beta\alpha}$ is the amplitude including virtual photons only with momenta greater then $\Lambda$. We also have that $0<\lambda\le \Lambda$.
$\Lambda$ is the threshold that defines when a photon is soft, while $\lambda$ is an IR regulator.
From what I understood, the exponential on the RHS is the factor that gives the radiative corrections of soft photons, but only among external lines. It seems to me that this formula does not take into account corrections of virtual soft photons (i.e. with momenta $\lambda \le |\boldsymbol{q}|\le \Lambda$) inside the diagram. Why we are not considering them? They should also contribute to the IR divergences.

The soft virtual photons inside the diagram do not contribute to the $\frac{1}{q^0}$ pole. The reason is that the pole comes by considering a new contribution that looks like (using the $-+++$ signature)
$$\frac{\text{stuff}}{(p-q)^2 + m^2 - i \epsilon} \approx \frac{\text{other stuff}}{p \cdot q + i \epsilon},$$
where $p$ is the momentum of the line to which you attached the soft photon and $q$ is the momentum of the soft photon. You get a pole in the right-hand side because the line to which you attached the soft photon is on-shell, and thus you can write $p^2 = - m^2$ and simplify the denominator. If the line was not on-shell (which is the case for the internal lines you're interested in), the cancellation does not happen and there is no additional pole. Hence, these contributions are not relevant to the divergences Weinberg is studying.

Let me mention that when I was first studying this topic, I found Weinberg's original paper (Phys. Rev. D 140 B516 (1965)) extremely illuminating. Andy Strominger's lectures notes (arXiv: 1703.05448) were also extremely helpful. (Weinberg's book is also a great source, but you already know that)
