Decay rate including soft virtual corrections
In Weinberg Volume I section 13.2, the author claims that (eq.13.2.11) is always positive:
\begin{equation}
A(\alpha\to \beta)= -\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\sum_{nm}\frac{e_ne_m\eta_n\eta_m}{\beta_{nm}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{nm}}{1-\beta_{nm}}\right)>0,\tag{13.2.11}
\end{equation}
where the $n,m$ are the external fields of the process $\alpha \to \beta$, $\eta_n = +1$ if particle $n$ is outgoing, $\eta_m = -1$ if particle $m$ is incoming, $e_n$ is the charge of the type $n$ field and $\beta_{nm}$ is the relative velocity of particle $n$ wrt particle $m$.
I don't understand how to show that this is always true.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/834386/2451

I will attempt an answer to your problem. One needs to keep in mind that $0\le\beta_{nm}\le1$.
Now, let us check the simplest case: the $1\rightarrow1$ scattering. In this scattering, I will label the initial particle with the number $1$ and the final particle with the number $2$. Then, $n=\{1,2\}$. The same goes for $m$.
Let us analyze that sum now. Upon expanding the sum wrt $m$, the latter takes the form
$$A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)=
-\frac{e_1\eta_1}{8\pi^2}\sum_{n}\frac{e_n\eta_n}{\beta_{n1}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{n1}}{1-\beta_{n1}}\right)-
\frac{e_2\eta_2}{8\pi^2}\sum_{n}\frac{e_n\eta_n}{\beta_{n2}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{n2}}{1-\beta_{n2}}\right)
$$
Expand, now, the sum wrt $n$ and get
$$A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)=
-\frac{e_1\eta_1}{8\pi^2}\frac{e_1\eta_1}{\beta_{11}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{11}}{1-\beta_{11}}\right)-
\frac{e_1\eta_1}{8\pi^2}\frac{e_2\eta_2}{\beta_{21}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{21}}{1-\beta_{21}}\right)\\-
\frac{e_2\eta_2}{8\pi^2}\frac{e_1\eta_1}{\beta_{12}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{12}}{1-\beta_{12}}\right)-
\frac{e_2\eta_2}{8\pi^2}\frac{e_2\eta_2}{\beta_{22}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{22}}{1-\beta_{22}}\right)
$$
Now, take into account that $\beta_{ij}=0$ for $i=j$, and that for such cases
$$
\frac{1}{\beta_{ii}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{ii}}{1-\beta_{ii}}\right)=2
$$
(no summation over repeated indices implied). Then, and since $\beta_{ij}=\beta_{ji}$,
$$
A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)=-
\frac{e_1^2}{8\pi^2}\times 2-
2\frac{e_1\eta_1}{8\pi^2}\frac{e_2\eta_2}{\beta_{21}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{21}}{1-\beta_{21}}\right)-
\frac{e_2^2}{8\pi^2}\times 2$$
Additionally, charge conservation implies that $e_1=e_2=e$ and
$$
A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)=-
\frac{e^2}{8\pi^2}\times 2+
2\frac{e^2}{8\pi^2}\frac{1}{\beta_{21}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\beta_{21}}{1-\beta_{21}}\right)-
\frac{e^2}{8\pi^2}\times 2$$
If one takes into account that
$$
\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)>2\ \text{for}\ x>0$$
it is obvious that $A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)>0$ for this simple $1\rightarrow1$ interaction.
To complete our proof, we note that every other interaction will contain a sum that will be comprised by "self-interaction" terms like our first and last, and "cross-interaction" terms, just like the one in the middle in a way that produces always a positive result for $A(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$. It's a good exercise to work out the details of $2\rightarrow2$ scattering and figure out how this summation works. This should be sufficient for understanding the more general case...
I hope this helps. If not, please comment.
